# javascript - moving an image left depending on the size of the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to use jquery cycle to rotate some images on my page. The images are 1400px wide, which means that for people with smaller screen resolutions, the right hand side of the image ends up dissappearing.

I want to make it so that the images looses an equal amount on either side of the image and thus keep the center of the image in the center of the viewing window.

If you look at http://renegadeox.com/ and resize your browser window you'll see what I mean.

How can I use javascript to move the image left relative to the container and thereby keep the image centred?

Here's the code for completeness:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshowWrap').cycle({
            fx: 'fade', // http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ Background rotater
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto" class="slideshowWrap">
        <div class="homeslideshow">
            <img src="background_01.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="homeslideshow">
            <img src="background_02.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="homeslideshow">
            <img src="background_03.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the custom transitions from the cycle plugin, to define your own method, to compute the correct left value you can use this code

**EDIT**

I tried this code and it works, however this only works on the load event, it doesn't work on resize, you might get the desired effect if you bind the whole function to the resize event

you also have to add a little css:

```
<style>
.slideshowWrap{
    width:100% !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

And this is the js that worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var leftVal = 0;
    if($(window).width()<1400){
        leftVal = ((1400 - $(window).width())/2)*-1;
    }

    $('.slideshowWrap').cycle({
        fx:      'custom',
        cssBefore: { 
            left: leftVal, 
            top:  0,  
            opacity: 1,
    display: 'block'
        },
        animOut: { 
            opacity: 0 
        },
        animIn: { 
            left: leftVal, 
            top: 0, 
        },
        cssAfter: { 
            zIndex: 0
        },
    cssFirst: {
    left: leftVal
    },
        delay: -3000
    });
});
</script>
```

I believe the above code would give you the desired effect, if not at least an idea of how to accomplish this, hope it helps!!
here is a link to the full docs on cycle custom fx http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv.html

Comment: Hey there javiercf - thanks for the input. I've given it a go but I can't get it working. I don't really know javascript that well but I understand what is meant to be happening here, but unfortunately for me the 1st image fades out and then there's nothing. Plus the 1st image isn't centred in the middle of the page in the first place :(

Comment: I just edited the code, you where right, it didn't work, the new one does the trick!

Comment: You're a freaking genius man! Woohoo!! It works! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Plus not sure what you mean it won't work on resize - it seems to work every way I can conceive of. If I drag the right of my browser window to make it narrower, it all still works fine... thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have images, can you use background images? Why not just use css?

It will be responsive, but if you want to make the plugin resize itself as the user changes browsers size - it will need to be updated on window resize event.

Otherwise if someone with low res screeen opens the page, the slider will always be 100% of their screen and images will be centered (and "cropped")

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .slideshowWrap {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .homeslideshow {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .slide1 {
            background: url(background_01.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        }
        .slide2 {
            background: url(background_02.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        }
        .slide3 {
            background: url(background_03.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        }
        .homeslideshow img {  display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slideshowWrap').cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                slideResize: 0
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto" class="slideshowWrap">
        <div class="homeslideshow slide1">
            <img src="background_01.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="homeslideshow slide2">
            <img src="background_02.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="homeslideshow slide3">
            <img src="background_03.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried your code - http://renegadeox.com/kasperoo.php - and it makes the image move over to the right. I don't think I understand what's meant to be happening. What am I missing?

Comment: If you have a small screen and open the page which you just linked, you will see that the image will be centred within the slider.  However if you resize your browser you will have to update the plugin because it won't be responsive.

Comment: sorry, another comment - I've added { slideResize: 0 } option to my answer thus making it all responsive and hopefully what you are looking for.